# How to focus a <tr> or <td> tag using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
for(var i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
    var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if(td[2].innerHTML==time && td[3].innerHTML==cls){
        td[0].setAttribute("id","focus");
        tr[i].style.backgroundColor="green";
        var foc = document.getElementById("focus");
        foc.focus();
        cnt++;
    }
    else{
        tr[i].style.backgroundColor="transparent";
    }

 }
```

Comment: I don't believe you can set a focus to a TD or TR. I think you can only set the focus to an input box of some sort... possibly a link.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you trying to rewrite this with jQuery?

Comment: You don't focus on a tr or a td, you can only focus on an input field. You are also setting two objects to the same id: your newly created input element *and* a td. An id *must* be unique on any given page. I would suggest using Firefox + Firebug and setting a breakpoint at `foc.focus();` and do a little variable inspecting.

Comment: He wants to set the focus of the user to a tr or td. But I don't believe it is possible, as you can't set a focus to anything but a input or link.

Comment: how focussed td different that blurred?

Comment: @Peter: Why must it be unique? It's intended to be unique, and semantically it should be, but nothing really enforces this.

Comment: I think he wants to add textbox to td and then focus it.

Comment: @Mark: If its not unique some browser implementation will fail to locate particular element

Comment: @teks Can you describe what you're trying to do?  It looks to me like you're just trying to highlight a row by changing its background.

Answer (score 9):

This is a year too late, but you *CAN* focus to a TD element. Just give it a tabindex property, and then do a focus().

This works for DIV elements and almost all others.

I've tried this on Firefox 3.5 and up.

Comment: Seems that wrapping table needs to have some id to make this work

Answer (score 2):

As the question is about changing the focus on a TD or TR, then the answer is that you cannot focus on such HTML tags; you can change the currently focused element if that is a input element (textarea, textfield, checkbox, radios) or a link, which are highlighted in a particular way when you click the key tab.
If you are really trying to focus on an input field, as suggested by Jonathan Sampson, then the answer he gave is the correct one.

In your code you are really trying to get the focus on a tag TD, then the answer to the question is no.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have an input field with the id "focus" within a td, so I'm assuming you want to focus on that input itself. With jQuery, you would do this:

```
$("input#focus").focus();
```

This will cause the focus to be brought to that particular element once called. I see that you also tried setting the ID of a particular TD to "focus" as well; you should only use a unique ID value once per page. If you feel the need to use a single value to represent many elements, consider using classnames instead as there can exist any number of them on a page.