# ASP.NET GridView within Scrollable Div: Scroll to SelectedIndex

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview, scrolltop, selectedindex

I have a GridView contained within a scrollable div. I also have a Button that selects a row in this GirdView based upon the text of a TextBox on the page. The row is selected just fine, but I cannot get the div to scroll to the selected row programmatically. I have attempted multiple methods involving JavaScript's "scrollTop" method, but for some reason I cannot get them to work correctly. Here is my code so far (some of the code for the "btnGo_OnClick" method is taken from an answer to a similar question on the asp.net forums, but it does not appear to be working for me):

The .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="StudentList.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <br />
    <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 400px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="StudentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DataSource1"
            AllowSorting="true" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Email">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MiddleInitial" HeaderText="Middle" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MiddleInitial" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GPA" HeaderText="GPA" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="GPA" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit1" Text="Edit" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit1_OnClick" />
                        &nbsp
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    Search by Last Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp
    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" Text="Go" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnGo_OnClick" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/University(2).accdb"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [LastName], [FirstName], [MiddleInitial], [Phone], [Email], [GPA] 
FROM [Students] ORDER BY [LastName]" DeleteCommand=""></asp:AccessDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

And the .aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnDelete_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow containingRow = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            String strEmail = containingRow.Cells[4].Text;
            DataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" + strEmail + "'";
            DataSource1.Delete();
            DataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE [Email] = '" + strEmail + "'";
            DataSource1.Delete();
            StudentList.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnEdit1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow containingRow = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            Session["Email"] = containingRow.Cells[4].Text;
            Response.Redirect("~/StudentEdit.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnGo_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in StudentList.Rows)
            {
                if (rowItem.Cells[0].Text.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text))
                {
                    StudentList.SelectedIndex = i;
                int intScrollTo = this.StudentList.SelectedIndex * (int)this.StudentList.RowStyle.Height.Value;
                    string strScript = "";
                    strScript += "var gridView = document.getElementById('" + this.StudentList.ClientID + "');\n";
                    strScript += "if (gridView != null && gridView.parentElement != null && gridView.parentElement.parentElement != null)\n";
                    strScript += "  gridView.parentElement.parentElement.scrollTop = " + intScrollTo + ";\n";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "btnGo_OnClick", strScript, true);
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Can someone explain why it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Some bit of javascript can help. Have a look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4558637/145682

Here is a POC:

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewScrollIndex.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            height: 225px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function focusRow(id, rowIndex) {
            var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
            var rows = tbl.childNodes[0].childNodes;
            rows[rowIndex].childNodes[0].focus();
            document.getElementById('console').innerText = rows[rowIndex].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="padding:10px; background-color:lightblue; height:105px; overflow:scroll;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectIndexes" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" />
        <div id="console"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridViewScrollIndex
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
                GridView1.DataSource = arr;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                ddlSelectIndexes.DataSource = arr.Select(x=> new {f1=x, f2=x});
                ddlSelectIndexes.DataValueField = "f1";
                ddlSelectIndexes.DataTextField = "f2";
                ddlSelectIndexes.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selVal = ddlSelectIndexes.SelectedValue;
            int i=0;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {                    
                    if (row.Cells[0].Text == selVal)
                    {
                        GridView1.SelectedIndex = i;
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GridView1, this.GetType(), "highlight",
                            string.Format("window.onload = function() {2} focusRow('{0}', {1}); {3};", GridView1.ClientID, i+1, "{", "}"), true);
                        break;
                    }                    
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will adapt your idea for my code and report whether or not it is successful.

Comment: Debugging this example gives the following error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'childNodes': object is null or undefined" for the following line in the script in the Markup page: "rows[rowIndex].childNodes[0].focus();". Why is this?

Comment: Its possible you are getting the wrong reference. However I'd have to see your adapted code to be sure. Put in some site like pastebin. What browser are you using? In your debugger try letting me know what the following outputs: `rows[rowIndex].tagName`

Comment: My modified code has been uploaded as an answer to this question, along with details about my browser and the value you asked about.

Comment: @ScottRobertLane What version of IE are you using? Inside the js function your goal should be to seek the `tr` and its nested `td` element corresponding to the `rowIndex` value passed as argument to the function. So perhaps the subscript you are assigning to the `childNodes` property will vary...you have to debug and find this out

Comment: I have it working correctly now, deostroll. I went back to my original attempt (using the "scrollTop" method) and realized that the RowStyle.Height property had to be explicitly declared in the opening tag of the GridView, which I had not done. My corrected code will be posted as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

deostroll, I am using Internet Explorer. The rows[rowIndex].tagName propery appears to be null, as it cannot be displayed. Here is my modified code:

The .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="StudentList.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script>
        function focusRow(id, rowIndex) {
            var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
            var rows = tbl.childNodes[0].childNodes;
            alert(rows[rowIndex].tagName);
            rows[rowIndex].childNodes[0].focus();
        }
    </script>
    <br />
    <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 400px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="StudentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DataSource1"
            AllowSorting="true" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Email">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MiddleInitial" HeaderText="Middle" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MiddleInitial" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GPA" HeaderText="GPA" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="GPA" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit1" Text="Edit" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit1_OnClick" />
                        &nbsp
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    Search by Last Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp
    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" Text="Go" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnGo_OnClick" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/University(2).accdb"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [LastName], [FirstName], [MiddleInitial], [Phone], [Email], [GPA] 
FROM [Students] ORDER BY [LastName]" DeleteCommand=""></asp:AccessDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

The .aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnDelete_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow containingRow = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            String strEmail = containingRow.Cells[4].Text;
            DataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" + strEmail + "'";
            DataSource1.Delete();
            DataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE [Email] = '" + strEmail + "'";
            DataSource1.Delete();
            StudentList.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnEdit1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow containingRow = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            Session["Email"] = containingRow.Cells[4].Text;
            Response.Redirect("~/StudentEdit.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnGo_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in StudentList.Rows)
            {
                if (rowItem.Cells[0].Text.ToUpper().StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
                {
                    StudentList.SelectedIndex = i;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(StudentList, this.GetType(), "highlight",
                    string.Format("window.onload = function() {2} focusRow('{0}', {1}); {3};", StudentList.ClientID, i + 1, "{", "}"), true);
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it working correctly now. Here is my corrected code:

The .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="StudentList.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script>
        function focusRow(id, pxlAmount) {
            var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
            dTbl = tbl.parentElement.parentElement;
            dTbl.scrollTop = pxlAmount;
        }
    </script>
    <br />
    <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 400px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="StudentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DataSource1"
            AllowSorting="true" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Email" RowStyle-Height="40px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MiddleInitial" HeaderText="Middle" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MiddleInitial" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GPA" HeaderText="GPA" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="GPA" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit1" Text="Edit" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit1_OnClick" />
                        &nbsp
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    Search by Last Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp
    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" Text="Go" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnClick="btnGo_OnClick" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/University(2).accdb"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [LastName], [FirstName], [MiddleInitial], [Phone], [Email], [GPA] 
FROM [Students] ORDER BY [LastName]" DeleteCommand=""></asp:AccessDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

The .aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnDelete_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow containingRow = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            String strEmail = containingRow.Cells[4].Text;
            DataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [CoursesTaken] WHERE [StudentID] = '" + strEmail + "'";
            DataSource1.Delete();
            DataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE [Email] = '" + strEmail + "'";
            DataSource1.Delete();
            StudentList.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnEdit1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow containingRow = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            Session["Email"] = containingRow.Cells[4].Text;
            Response.Redirect("~/StudentEdit.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnGo_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow rowItem in StudentList.Rows)
            {
                if (rowItem.Cells[0].Text.ToUpper().StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
                {
                    StudentList.SelectedIndex = i;
                    int iScrollTo = (StudentList.SelectedIndex) * ((int)StudentList.RowStyle.Height.Value); /* RowStyle.Height must be explicitly defined in the opening tag of the GridView */
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(StudentList, this.GetType(), "highlight",
                    string.Format("window.onload = function() {2} focusRow('{0}', {1}); {3};", StudentList.ClientID, iScrollTo, "{", "}"), true);
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem ended up being something simple: I had not explicitly defined the RowStyle.Height Property of the GridView in its opening tag. Thus, this was being evaluated as "0" during the calculation of the position to scroll to in the div.