# Focus is not working for me

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very basic code:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 40){ //down arrow
        $('tbody').first('tr').focus();

    }else if(e.keyCode == 38){ //up arrow

    }
});
```

You can see that I check whether the up or down key is pressed. And if the down arrow is pressed the first `tr` in the `tbody` should be focused by Jquery. Which means this style should be added:

```
tr:focus{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

But somehow it doesn't work! Could you please revise it and give me a solution? Thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hye78/2/

Comment: `tr` doesnt have focus, only text input and so fourth.  See this post for more info [How to focus a <tr> or <td> tag using jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932152/how-to-focus-a-tr-or-td-tag-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this:

[**Living example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hye78/4/)

There's no `focus` state for the row, but you can replace it for a class. I've chosen the class `active` for it.

Also, the background should be applied to the `td` element, not the the `tr`.

```
tr.active td {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

This is the jQuery I used:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    var activeRow;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { //down arrow
        if (!$('tbody').find('tr.active').length) {
            activeRow = $('tbody').find('tr').first();
        } else {
            activeRow = $('tbody').find('tr.active').next();
        }

    }else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up arrow
         activeRow = $('tbody').find('tr.active').prev();
    }

    activeRow.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Men this is awesome! But i have one more little thing! Lets suppose i have in every row a attribute `data-link` for eg `<tr data-link="135"`> How can i trowh an alert `alert($(this).attr('data-link')` if the user clicks the enter key? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnSmith that's a completely different question. Please open a new question for it. Answers should be as clear as possible. If this answers your proposed question, please accept it for possible future users.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `tabindex="1"` to your `tr` and change your JS code a bit:

Have

```
 $('tbody tr:first').focus();
```

instead of

```
  $('tbody').first('tr').focus();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hye78/5/)

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/popeyuyu/3/edit)**

`tabindex` is here for us, than in jQ you can use a counter to focus your `TR` in a loop

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr tabindex="0"><td>TD1</td></tr>
      <tr tabindex="0"><td>TD2</td></tr>
      <tr tabindex="0"><td>TD3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

jQ:

```
var $tr = $('tr');     //cache your selectors!
var c = 0;             //current/counter
var n = $tr.length;    //num of TR elements

// here instead of /document/ use rather a static element ID selector
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){

  var k = e.which;
  if(k==40){           // DOWN
    ++c;
  }else if(k===38){    // UP
    --c;
  }
  c %= n;              // Loop counter
  $tr.eq(c).focus();   // Focus on current using .eq() method

});
```

Comment: YaY! I'm not the only one who makes use of `$(document).on`. But wait, this is the same guy who complained at me about speed issues? You know it's faster to use a `static parent`. :-P Just pickin' at ya! Have a great day Roko & All StackO Peeps!

Comment: @SpYk3HH hi bro, yes, while you're absolutely right about the downside of listening for events all the way up to document, if you take a look at the OP's demo the table is the first children of `body`. Tho you're right I'll edit my answer to point that out. Really appreciated your comment.

Comment: I appreciate your ability to comment back and forth, even with some cynicism, and not be like so many others are being lately (complete jerks, "my way or highway"). It is quite honestly refreshing. I was starting to lose hope in SO being a friendly place. Even I was starting to turn into a comment jerk! Faith in SO Restored!

Comment: @SpYk3HH I learned not to take anything personally. A good suggestion is a good suggestion. If it's arguable, than let it be arguable with proof or arguments. Have a nice time and don't loose faith. Never

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` can't accept focus by default. Focus is limited to form elements and links unless you've set tabindex for the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/hye78/7/

Answer (score 0):

here is solution :  [click here for live example](http://jsfiddle.net/hye78/6/)

jquery

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 40){ //down arrow
        $('tbody tr:nth-child(1)').addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

css

```
.highlight{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
```